# Local Storage push XML Object

Tags: javascript, html, xml, parsing, dom

I have a JS code which creates an XML and the parses it on the Local Storage. The problem is that i can't append more XML into the Local Storage. Example below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<club>
     <movie>
           <title> I Love Programming </title>
           <genre> Action </genre>
           <dir> Brian De Palma </dir>
           <year> 1900 </year>
     </movie>
</club>
```

I save the code above into the Local Storage, but If i want to save more of the same XML it creates another XML file, insted of **pushing it  on the existent file**.

```
function addXMLtoLocalStorage(e){
txt1 = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

        txt2 = `<club>`
        txt3 = `<movie>`
        txt4 = `<title>` +  userInput[0] + `</title>` 
        txt5 = `<genre>` +  userInput[1] + `</genre>` 
        txt6 = `<dir>` +  userInput[2] + `</dir>` 
        txt7 = `<year>` +  userInput[3] + `</year>` 
        txt8 = `</movie>`
        txt9 = `</club>`
        txt=txt1+txt2+txt3+txt4+txt5+txt6+txt7+txt8+txt9;  
        console.log(txt);




        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
        console.log(xmlDoc);
        localStorage.setItem('data', xmlDoc);
}
```

How can I append everytime i run the function the newly generated XML into the first XML File, insted of creating a new everytime?

Expected output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<club>
     <movie>
           <title> I Love Programming </title>
           <genre> Action </genre>
           <dir> Brian De Palma </dir>
           <year> 1900 </year>
     </movie>
</club>
<!--Now add the following info below, not creating a new XML file.-->
<club>
     <movie>
           <title> I Love Programming The Sequel </title>
           <genre> Action </genre>
           <dir> Brian De Palma </dir>
           <year> 1920 </year>
     </movie>
</club>
<!-- Every new Club instance is when the function above is runned -->
<club>
     <movie>
           <title> Help! Me </title>
           <genre> Thriller </genre>
           <dir> Spielberg </dir>
           <year> 2020 </year>
     </movie>
</club>
```

Comment: Get the old(stored) one first and then update old one with new xml. To get the item stored in use localStorage `localStorage.getItem('data');`

Comment: @SameerKhan Thanks, if you mind, could you explain a little bit how to develop what you said? Thanks!

Comment: Note that localStorage only stores *string* values. So parsing the XML before storing it into localStorage is an exercise in futility. You should store the string in localStorage and parse it on the way out of localStorage.

Comment: Where is `userInput` coming from?

Comment: @HereticMonkey coming from a form <form> tag

Answer (score 0):

```js
const title = document.querySelector('#title');
const genre = document.querySelector('#genre');
const director = document.querySelector('#director');
const year = document.querySelector('#year');
const xmlContainer = document.querySelector('#xml-container');

(function displayXml() {
 let data = localStorage.getItem('data');
  if (data) {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(data,"text/xml");
    xmlContainer.append(xmlDoc.documentElement);
  }
}())

function addXMLtoLocalStorage() {
 let data = localStorage.getItem('data');
  
  let newXmlData = `
    <club>
        <movie>
          <title>${title.value}</title>
          <genre>${genre.value}</genre>
          <dir>${director.value}</dir>
          <year>${year.value}</year>
        </movie>
     </club>
  `
  
  if (!data) {
   data = "";
    data = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` + newXmlData;
  } else {
   data += newXmlData;
  }
  localStorage.setItem('data', data);
  parser = new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(data,"text/xml");
  console.log(data);
  xmlContainer.append(xmlDoc.documentElement);
  title.value = genre.value = director.value = year.value = null;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Title" id="title">
<input type="text" placeholder="genre" id="genre">
<input type="text" placeholder="Director" id="director">
<input type="number" placeholder="Year" id="year">
<button onclick="addXMLtoLocalStorage()">Add</button>
<div id="xml-container"></div>
```

**Some Details**

You can make use of template literals `${}`.
`${What you write in between of these, is treated as variables}`

Get The save data
`let data = localStorage.getItem('data');`
and append newly created xml as
`data += newXmlData;`

For Some reasons stackoverflow's run editor is not working please have a look in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sameerthekhans/96Lktgeb/)